# Image file path in Razor .cshtml view file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-1.0

In the website I'm creating, I'm trying to store a URL to an uploaded image into my model and calling to it in the view. So when I type out the file path in the source for the HTML, it works fine.

```
<dd><img src="~/uploads/image.jpg" alt="ASP.NET" style="width:350px;height:260px" />
    </dd>
```

But if I try to call from the model, the URL gets messed up.

```
@string imagePath = "~/uploads/" + Model.Picture;

 <dd><img src=@imagePath alt="ASP.NET" style="width:350px;height:260px" />
    </dd>
```

That code links to "http://localhost:60847/Controller/Details/~/uploads/image.jpg" . Could someone explain to me why it's working differently? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing quotes around the src property value. Also make sure you use the `Url.Content` helper method to get the correct path. You may pass `"~"` to this method to get the correct path to your app root.

```
@{ string imagePath = Url.Content("~/uploads/" + Model.Picture); };
<img src="@imagePath" alt="ASP.NET" style="width:350px;height:260px" />
```

**Or** even a single liner without the variable

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/uploads/" + Model.Picture)"  />
```

Comment: Okay the Url.Content helper fixed it, thank you. I've tried with and without the quotes for the src property value and both work once the Url.Content helper was used.

Comment: You should use quotes. What if your `Model.Picture` value has a space in it  ? Your code will break if you do not have quotes.

Comment: Okay, so Razor doesn't automatically put in quotes even if it's a string data type?

Comment: No. You need to do it yourself. Razor will render the value of the expression.